# When did bombs start having fancy countdown timers?

Tags: first-appearance, props

I think that it's widely considered that bombs with cute LCD displays and timers displaying the time left, all in movies and video games, are highly unrealistic, because what evil villain wants to let the good guys know how much time they have left?

The earliest I can recall that maybe the oldest instance of bombs with timers were maybe the dynamites with the string hanging out in the old Looney Toons, but someone has me convinced that there is a far older iteration of the "bomb with a timer to kindly let the good guys know how long they have to save the world" kind of thing.

Comment: TV Tropes - http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimeBomb

Comment: Removed Lethal Weapon tag as it relates to film.

Comment: Not really what you're after, but a clever alternative that uses clocks can be found in [that tense scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qukz70OaYf0) in Hitchcock's Sabotage where a kid carries a bomb around.

Comment: Do you expect me to talk?